# Comparator have hysteresis with pull-up resistor?

Tags: comparator, pullup, hysteresis

I didn't add any hysteresis to below circuit but there's ~500 mV delay between output going high and low,  output goes high at 7.5 V but goes low at 7 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCMzt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think the current through the pull-up resistor keeps the transistor on but isn't the LM393 supposed to prevent that by sinking the pull-up current to ground so the output can be without any hysteresis?

What is causing this unwanted hysteresis?

Comment: "delay" ... there will be a propagation delay in all parts which may present itself as equivalent to hysteresis but do not confuse a transport delay with threshold hysteresis

Comment: What is your input signal and what frequency is it?

Comment: @Andyaka It's DC voltage.

Comment: How are you determining "output goes high"? Measuring the voltage directly at the op-amp, or when the relay activates?

Comment: I did both if your read my chat with Spehro. with and without relay and or transistor, directly at output etc. it was stray capacitance causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As it turns out from OP, the cause was unwanted feedback, likely causing high-frequency oscillation. Reducing the impedance at the non-inverting input by 10:1 by changing the resistor values cured the symptom.

In general it is a good idea to have a bypass capacitor across the supply rails near the chip and to bypass any slow-moving or DC input such as the reference voltage in the above circuit with a capacitor to ground. In this case, something like 100nF would be appropriate. OP could then most likely go back to the higher values and waste less power.

Solderless breadboards, as OP used, have a certain amount of parasitic capacitance between rows of connections, several pF or more, and although that is often not of much concern, it can cause issues in some cases, even where high frequencies are not *intended* to be present.

A coupling of only 5pF could cause this amount of oscillation with ~6.9K source impedance at only ~150kHz, which is well within the capabilities of that comparator.

---

Possibly the current drawn by the relay coil is dragging the 24V nominal supply down by 1.6V, which would cause the hysteresis you are seeing.

You can add a voltage regulator (series or shunt) or a zener diode regulator to stabilize your reference.

You **must** also have a flyback diode across the relay, which could conceivably be causing the problem. Try it without the relay connected at all and see what happens.

Comment: The 24V reference voltage is directly from the 7824 regulator and it's not dropping, relay is only drawing 8 mA.

Comment: See edit--- flyback diode is not optional.

Comment: Flyback diode is connected, I disconnected the relay and measured the output voltage. output doesn't go to the positive rail, only to ~12 V, output voltage decrease gradually as the positive input reference decreases. but instantly goes to 12 V.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some AC ripple on your 8V or 24V inputs? Oscilloscope?

Comment: I just scoped the 24 V rail just to be sure and it's dead linear, also see the edit I made to my second comment (should've written decrease instead of increase.). maybe the chip is damaged? I bought two and both behaving the same.

Comment: Maybe there is something up with the chip, but strange.

Comment: Increasing the pull-up resistor to 100K solves the problem to some degree though...

Comment: Removed the transistor and now the output goes to 24 V but yet slowly goes to the negative supply not instantly, replaced the transistor too. transistor looks fine.

Comment: Found the problem, the voltage divider resistors was too big. reduced them to 2.2K and 1K and it solved the problem. any idea why that was happening? was it related to input current biasing?

Comment: I suspect it was oscillating. A capacitor to ground on the input is often a good idea.

Comment: The comparator itself? what was causing it?

Comment: Stray feedback capacitance or possibly bad layout somewhere else, but the fact it continued with the relay disconnected makes me suspect stray capacitance.

Comment: It's on the breadboard, that explain it well. can you please add it to the answer?

Comment: I have added it with some additional explanation.

Comment: I just added the 22k and 10K resistors again and a 1uF capacitor to the output, that solves the problem. your guess was right (as always), it was oscillating.

Comment: 1uF from input to ground, I hope?

Comment: No from output to the ground, should it be on the input?

Comment: Yes, input to ground

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.